# How solve cURL error 60: SSL certificate in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using "FriendsOfPHP/Goutte" Package https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte
For web crawling... When I use "http://" links then it's ran correctly but when I use "https://" then show the following errors...

> 2/2
>   RequestException in RequestException.php line 51:
>   cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate:

```php
$client->getClient()
       ->setDefaultOption('config/curl/' . CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: `RuntimeException in Client.php line 289:
no api namespace found: getClient`  This error is showing after using `$nexmo = app('Nexmo\Client');
              $nexmo->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/' . CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$nexmo->message()->send([
    'to' => ''.$mobile.'',
    'from' => '918269871472',
    'text' => ''.$message.'',
]);` this code. @Bogdan

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a certificate problem.
It seems `Goutte` depends on `Guzzle 4`. And Guzzle can't find the proper certificate to verify a secure `https` request, see more about it [here](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify).

Try to download this file: [Bundle of CA Root Certificates](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) 
. (`Open` and `Save As`).

Then locate your php.ini file and add,or edit if it already exists, this line

`curl.cainfo = "[pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem"`