# Error 64 SSL certificate laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

I am getting this error when logging into Facebook on my localhost:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate:

```
$client->getClient()
   ->setDefaultOption('config/curl/' . CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Got answer from: [see Bondan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403356/1960558)

OR See this answer: [cURL error 60 while facebook Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084512/1960558)